# Memoir footnotes in margin with ragged2e

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, double-sided, marginpar, ragged2e

I would like to set up `memoir` so that when I use `\footnote{foo}`, `foo` is displayed in the margin with the proper label and preferably break over pages.

There is an option `\footnotesinmargin` which gives almost exactly what I need, only justified. I want it to use `ragged2e` and change alignment based on even/odd page so that the margin note is always flushed towards the main text area and allows hyphenation on the side of the edge.

```
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{memoir}
\footnotesinmargin
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]\footnote{\kant[1]}
\kant[2]\footnote{\kant[2]}
\kant[3-5]
\end{document}
```

### Possible partial work-around

I have remembered a nice thesis based upon the Classic thesis template and found the [source](https://github.com/jrk/uggedal-thesis/blob/master/src/uiothesis.cls) which indeed contains a possible solution:

```
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\sidemark}[1]{#1.{\:}}

\newcommand{\marginelement}[2][0]{%
  \marginnote{%
    \strictpagechecktrue
    \checkoddpage
    \ifoddpage%
      \RaggedRight\footnotesize%
    \else%
      \RaggedLeft\footnotesize%
    \fi%
    #2%
  }[#1\onelineskip]%
}%

\newcommand{\sidenote}[2][0]{%
  \footnotemark%
  \ignorespaces%
  \marginelement[#1]{%
    \sidemark{\thefootnote}%
    \ignorespaces#2%
  }%
  \unskip%
}%
```

Nevertheless, I would still prefer a memoir-specific solution with the re-definition of footnotes when used with the option `\footnotesinmargin` mainly for the sake of portability. This work-around also **does not work with hyperref** (there is no hypertext connection) and **does not break over pages** automatically.

Comment: In my experience, it is (virtually) impossible to get all three things together for a marginal note: page-breaking (esp. *within* paragraphs); context-sensitive justification; and floating notes.  If your notes are as long as a `\kant[1]`, a solution will be difficult.

Comment: @jon Are you familiar with `\sidefootnote` from `memoir`? It is aligned to bottom and breaks over pages, so perhaps I could use a combination of two: a) `\footnote` with `\footnotesinmargin` for short notes horizontally aligned with the text, and b) `\sidefootnote` for long notes that need to be broken across pages. The problem is that the latter is not aligned to the text on even pages. Could you suggest such a solution, please?

Comment: Yes I am.  My suspicion for why `memoir` *adds* `\sidenote`, `\sidebar`, and `\sidefootnote` (are there others?) rather than just makes *one* command that can be made to do all of these things is because it is super-difficult to implement.  (I stopped saying impossible regarding tricky implementations because everytime I did, someone would come up with a solution.)  Anyway, I looked briefly this morning at how the different marginal notes were implemented, but it doesn't seem easy to combine them at all.  I hope to look again tonight, but I'm on a deadline, so it may not happen.

Comment: @jon Also `\marginpar` and `\sidepar` as far as I am aware. You can see my solution resorting to the use of two different functions and some additional tweaks below. If you produce anything better, I will gladly accept it. You are probably right that there is a reason for this mess, although I remain oblivious to the technical background that makes the implementation of such functionality so difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I have finally figured it out but I am not going to accept this answer yet because I think it can be done better.

I am combining the use of `\footnote` with the option `\footnotesinmargin` and `\sidefootnote`. The former can be used to make a margin note vertically aligned with the reference mark and is intended for short notes that do not break across pages while the latter is aligned at the bottom of a page, breaks across pages, and is intended for longer notes or if you are running out of space.

Both are hacked to become `\RaggedRight` or `\RaggedLeft` based on whether the page on which they appear is even or odd by this code:

### Modify the behaviour of `\footnote`:

```
\makeatletter  % All between \makeatletter and \makeatother originally located in memoir.cls
\renewcommand{\@footnotetext}[1]{%
  \ifm@mfnmargin%   use marginpar
    \marginpar{%
    \def\baselinestretch{\m@m@footnote@spacing}%
    \reset@font
    \foottextfont
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
      \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{\ignorespaces
        \strictpagechecktrue         % <-- Start of change
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \scriptsize\RaggedRight
  \else
    \scriptsize\RaggedLeft
  \fi #1}%                             <-- End of change
    \color@endgroup}%
  \else% regular feet
    \insert\footins{%
    \def\baselinestretch{\m@m@footnote@spacing}%
    \reset@font
    \foottextfont
    \@preamfntext
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
      \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces{\foottextfont #1}%
        \@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}%
  \fi%
  \m@mmf@prepare}
\makeatother
\footnotesinmargin
```

### Modify the behaviour of `\sidefootnote`:

```
\renewcommand{\sidefoottextfont}{%
  \strictpagechecktrue
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \scriptsize\RaggedRight
  \else
    \scriptsize\RaggedLeft
  \fi
 }%
```

### Additional modifications

You might also want to add

```
\letcountercounter{sidefootnote}{footnote}
```

if you want to combine their counters into one, and

```
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{-\footmarkwidth}
\setlength{\footparindent}{1em}
```

to modify the appearance of `\footnote` side notes in order to match `\sidefootnote`.

Finally, I must say that TeX is the definition of chaos.

Answer (score 2):

You want to be manipulating the `\foottextfont`.

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{memoir}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\footnotesinmargin
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{%
  \strictpagechecktrue
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \scriptsize\RaggedRight
  \else
    \scriptsize\RaggedLeft
  \fi
 }%
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]\footnote{\kant[1]}
\kant[2]\footnote{\kant[2]}
\kant[3-5]
\end{document}
```

Note though that with such heavy margin material, the chances of you being able to have the notes placed correctly is slim.  I ran into a similar problem with my thesis and wound up increasing the margin space so that I wouldn't have a problem like the one in this example (where footnote #2 winds up on the wrong page).

Comment: Can you give a full example?  Manipulating `foottextfont` does not work for footnotes turned into marginpars via `\footnotesinmargin`.

Comment: This compiled just fine for me, although as I point out, if using `marginfix` the second footnote gets bumped to the following page so it won't overflow.

Comment: @Alexander I think you misunderstood my objective. I have just compiled your example and the problem still persists. The margin note in the picture should be aligned to the right. http://s2.postimg.org/r5s4uax8p/test.png I have already tried manipulating `\foottextfont` and none of my approaches worked. The documentation says nil.

Comment: Successful compilation, sure; but it doesn't actually change any behaviour for *marginal* notes...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to get it to break across pages, but for justification there is an extremely simple fix.

**Background**

The `memoir` class provides a `\mpjustification` command, which is enabled by calling either of:

1. `\marginparmargin{}`

`outer` is the default, which sets margin notes on the fore-edge. This also sets up the below command.

2. `\setmpjustification{}{}`

`\raggedleft` and `\raggedright` are default, which you might like to change to `\RaggedLeft` and `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package.

The `\mpjustification` command will justify following text depending on what page the text appears on.

**Solution**

Manipulating the `\foottextfont` command isn't enough, since this is just a command that appears inside a footnote, and not before it. Basically, you need to be setting up the justification before the footnote is output at all. It's very simple, just put the below after any footnote styling commands:

```
\let\oldfootnot\footnote
\renewcommand*{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\mpjustification#1}}
```

`\footnote` will now set the text in the margin, justified flush against the type block.

Comment: Typo in the first line of **Solution**: should read `\let\oldfootnote\footnote`.